# COMPOSER.json install with dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, dockerfile

> ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder719265864/composer.json: no such
>   file or directory

Docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
    - .:/var/www
    - .:/var/www/vendor/
```

Dockerfile

```
# Install composer
WORKDIR /var/www/

RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git zip

RUN curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

COPY ./ /var/www/

RUN php composer.phar install
```

My composer.json is in /src in my folder.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "slim/slim": "^3.11",
    "slim/php-view": "^2.0",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17"
},
```

I wanna run my composer.json when i build.

Comment: why are you copying? your files should just be mounted

Comment: Here's mine if you want to compare settings (or even just use it) https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Comment: Now i get that

Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c php composer.phar install' returned a non-zero code: 1

How i specify the composer path ?

Comment: I wanna just initiate on Dockerfile my composer.json

Answer (score -3):

```
# Install composer
RUN echo pwd: `pwd` && echo ls: `ls`  # outputs:
                                      # pwd: /
                                      # ls:

#Copiando projeto para o container
COPY composer.lock /var/www/html
COPY composer.json /var/www/html
COPY logs /var/www/html/logs
COPY public /var/www/html/public
COPY src /var/www/html/src

VOLUME /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN pwd

# Allow Composer to be run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

# Setup the Composer installer
RUN curl -o /tmp/composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer \
  && curl -o /tmp/composer-setup.sig https://composer.github.io/installer.sig \
  && php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.php')) !== trim(file_get_contents('/tmp/composer-setup.sig'))) { unlink('/tmp/composer-setup.php'); echo 'Invalid installer' . PHP_EOL; exit(1); }" \
  && php /tmp/composer-setup.php \
  && chmod a+x composer.phar \
  && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

# Install composer dependencies
RUN echo pwd: `pwd` && echo ls: `ls`  # outputs:
                                      # pwd: /var/www/html
                                      # ls:

RUN /usr/local/bin/composer install

#RUN /usr/local/bin/composer update


# Install composer dependencies
RUN echo pwd: `pwd` && echo ls: `ls`  # outputs:
                                      # pwd: /var/www/html
                                      # ls:
```